# Spartacus B2B Sample files

Tags: spartacus-storefront, b2b

Are there any sample data available for B2B features in Spartacus? All the files that I could find were referencing old (on-prem) storefront.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

B2B sample data comes packaged with the latest spartacus releases in the 2005 sample data addons attached to releases.

https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/releases

Comment: thanx! Maybe it would be useful to post the direct [link](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/releases/download/storefront-3.0.2/spartacussampledata.2005.tar.gz) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually according to your SAP Commerce version you'll find the Sample data and how to install it here:

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/